# Travelling from USA to Canada and return

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

I have an esta.  I am flying into USA, staying overnight before travelling to Canada by land arriving in Canada 12 hours later.
I will be in Canada 100 days.
Will I be able to return by land to USA to allow me to fly home?

Comment: @CMaster: Not sure it is an exact duplicate. In the earlier question the asker would be _flying_ from USA to Canada, so his exit would be registered with the US authorities. In this case, where the OP leaves by land (and doesn't have a paper I-94 to turn in at that point), I think he might need additional advice about how to document that he left the US just a day after entering.

Comment: @HenningMakholm oops yes, the other duplicate suggested is the better one.